# Smarty prints a WHITE SPACE between variables (in Loop)?

Tags: php, loops, smarty, whitespace, space

Assigning from PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("myArrays", Array(
                   Array( "title" => "ABC", "whatever" => 45),
                   Array( "title" => "DEF", "whatever" => 78)
               ));
```

In Smarty (v3.1.16) `.tpl` file:

```
{assign "seperator" "|"}
{foreach from=$myArrays item=currentItem}
    {$seperator}{$currentItem.title}{$seperator}
{/foreach}
```

Then it will output as:

```
|ABC| |DEF|
```

.. **WITH A "SPACE" in-between**.
And i think it is only in such LOOPS.

Why is so?
And how to solve it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use no spaces in the loop:

```
{foreach from=$myArrays item=currentItem}{$seperator}{$currentItem.title}{$seperator}{/foreach}
```

or use the smarty directive to make smarty remove spaces: [`{strip}/{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.strip.tpl):

```
{strip}
    {foreach from=$myArrays item=currentItem}
        {$seperator}{$currentItem.title}{$seperator}{/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/strip}
```

Comment: It work! BUT seriously, why is it so please? :S Obviously it is like a BUG since no one will prefer to have a Additional White Space without needing it.

Comment: ain't no bug, html spaces are relevant (in text) that's all, please read the doc of `{strip}' I linked (especially the linked doc for the `strip` directive).

Comment: Hi @RC. (since i hope you are familiar with Smarty), could you please look into this problem also, please? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952796/smarty-to-line-break-when-write-into-file) Thanks much. :)