# Smarty to LINE-BREAK when write into FILE?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, newline, line-breaks

I have a Smarty Loop as below, for e.g:

```
{strip}
    {assign "comma" ""}
    {foreach from=$List item=Item}
        {$comma}{$Item.title}
        {assign "comma" ","}
    {/foreach}
{/strip}
```

.. from which **I EXPECT** is:

```
Apple,
Banana,
Candy
```

.. WRITTEN as a FILE.

My PHP codes (to write the file) are:

```
$f = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
fwrite( $f, $smarty->fetch('sample.tpl') );
```

But instead **IN REALITY**, it is being written as like below:

```
Apple,Banana,Candy
```

Even if i use `\r` or `\r\n` in Smarty `tpl`, they are just being printed out, as the characters themselfs.
**Not breaking the lines anyway**.

How to do it please?

Comment: old question but.. `{$item.title}{"\n"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc of [`{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.strip.tpl) I quoted [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21952072/180100) *(and asked you to read)*:

> Anything within `{strip}{/strip}` tags are stripped of the extra spaces **or carriage returns** at 
>   the beginnings and ends of the lines before they are displayed. This way you can keep your 
>   templates readable, and not worry about extra white space causing problems.

One solution:

```
{strip}
    {foreach name=foo from=$List item=Item}
            {$Item.title}{if !$smarty.foreach.foo.last}{literal},
{/literal}{/if}
    {/foreach}
{/strip}
```

Strip remove blanks and literal force `,<newline>` to be the separator. NB: spaces and newline **are** meaningful between `{literal}` and `{/literal}`

(tested with smarty 3.1.16)

Comment: OMG it makes me the code unnecessarily complicated than it should :(